# Cordova: 'Windows is undefined' on UWP app

Tags: javascript, cordova, win-universal-app, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to migrate a Win/WinPhone 8.1 app to a Win10 (UWP) package.

So far the app is building fine and running, but crashes on first reference on Windows component:

> **Windows is undefined**

(e.g. on accessing *Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current*)

Some facts:

- WinJS (base.js) is loaded before cordova.js
- **WinJS is available** in global namespace - Windows is not
- UseDotNetNativeToolchain property is set to true on *.jsproj
- using Cordova Windows v.4.4.3 / WinJS 4.4.0

On Try-And-Error I also added some references like *Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP* or *Microsoft .NET Native Runtime Package for Windows* , but that wasn't the reason.

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: I do not use cordova, but in JS there is `window`, not `windows`. Maybe you can provide SO Snippet with issue?

Comment: Yeah right on the browser `window` is the global object. But I really mean `Windows` from the Windows API. Example would be `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings.values["Key"] = "Value";` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder and choose JavaScript on the right

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduced this problem. Could you please try it on an empty blank project?

Comment: Strangely it is working for a fresh project. I realized `var hasWinRT = !!_Global.Windows;` is false on base.js

Comment: @kerosene It looks like something is wrong in your project template, the simple way is to recreate the project and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error on the appxmanifest definition:

```
    <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
        <uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
    </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

wasn't set which caused that the Windows Runtime was not accessible.